# get prev ID-value form input="text"

Tags: jquery, closest

I can find a way to get the id = "*DropDownListA*". But I have to get the id-value by using **this**

Somehow `$(this).closest('input').attr('id')` is not working

```
<td align="right">
 <div class="farvorit_field" id="DivDropDownListA">
 <input type="text" id="DropDownListA" name="customerGroup" value="" size="35">
  <a href="#" title='See farvorits customers.'>
   <img onClick="alert($(this).parent('a').siblings(':text').attr('id'));" src="../img/info.gif" border="0">
  </a>
 </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this.

```
$(this).parent().prev().attr('id')
```

`.parent()` will give anchor element and then calling `.prev()` on it will give the `input` element.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WEgbn/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ID it is supposed to be the only one on the page, so why to make things complex and avoid the simplest `$('#DropDownListA').attr('id')`?
If you absolutely have to use word `this` then use @ShankarSangoli's solution.